# static method with a synchronized block inside, blocks the entire class in java?

Tags: java, synchronized, java-threads

I have a class that executes 3 threads, and on every thread I ask and check on the global variables. I´m trying to lock each variable separetly, I dont´t want to block the entire class every time I change one of the variables. I researched a little but I´m still confuse.
In this case, because I have to access the variables from each threads, I have to make the methods static, so my questions:  I´m blocking each variables or the entire class every time I call the getters and setters?

```
 public class MyClass {
    private static boolean bool1= false;
    private static boolean bool2= false;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //run Thread1
        //run Thread2
        //run thread3
    }


    private static Object lock1 = new Object();
    private static Object lock2 = new Object();

    public static boolean isBool1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            return bool1;
        }
    }

    public static void setBool1(boolean bool) {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            MyClass.bool1= bool1;
        }
    }


    public static boolean isBool2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            return bool2;
        }
    }

    public static void setBool2(boolean bool2) {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            MyClass.bool2= bool2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps make the relevant variables `volatile`?

Comment: No, you are not blocking the entire class.  Because you are inside a static method, there *is* no class object to block.

Comment: No, you're not locking on the class object since you're not declaring _the method_ as `synchronized` (e.g., `synchronized static void myMethod()` locks on the class object).

Answer (score 0):

No you are not blocking the class, your static methods are not declared as synchronized, nor are you blocking on an instance of the class because your class has no instances.

However, it is not necessary to declare your methods static in order to call them from separate threads. Your code would work the same way if you didn't declare anything static and called the methods on a single instance. It would also be a better approach, it is generally a bad idea to declare something static that does not need to be. It makes it hard to use your code in a multi-threaded or shared VM (e.g. application server) scenario.

Also there are often better ways to achieve thread safety than liberal use of the synchronized keyword on individual objects. You could consider using a BlockingQueue with a ThreadPoolExecutor configured to use a single thread.

Comment: Could you explain a little more why declaring methods as `static` could be a bad idea? I don't understand how it would make it hard to run the code with multiple threads.

Comment: Declaring methods static is not always a bad idea, for example if you are writing a method that takes one or more parameters and returns a value depending just on those parameters (neither accessing or muting data from the class or object). Factory methods are also an appropriate use of static.